# Marketing Cloud Connect Issue when updating Salesforce Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, marketing-cloud-connect

Until last week I was able to update information from Marketing Cloud to Sales using the following code. Since the last weekend it stopped working, anyone knows if there was any security release that could affect this functionality? As you can see the code is quite simple. Thanks in advance.

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
try {
    var dataExtensionLog = DataExtension.Init("6552MW3D-T522-4BB0-DD9A-554XXF4032T2");
    var recordsRetrieved = dataExtensionLog.Rows.Retrieve();
    for (var index in recordsRetrieved) {

        var ContactScore = parseInt(recordsRetrieved[index]['ContactScore__c']);
        var Id = recordsRetrieved[index]['Id'];
        var ampscriptFunction = '';

        ampscriptFunction = "%" + "%[UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Contact','" + Id + "','ContactScore__c','" + ContactScore + "')]%" + "%";
        Platform.Function.TreatAsContent(ampscriptFunction);

    }
} catch (e) {
    write(Stringify(e));
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the contents of the exception? Or is no exception thrown?

Comment: Can you also please confirm, does the above implementation is in production or Sandbox?